# How do i define a shortcut in bash script in select menus?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

How can i define a shortcut like "c" for "create", "d" for "delete" or "n" for "new" by select menus in shell scripts?

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Enter an option: "

select option in create delete new quit
do
    echo "Selected option was: $option"

if [ "$option" == "create" ]

then
 
read -r -p 'Create new partition: Please define a name of the partition: ' new_partition

read -r -p 'Define Size: Please define a size of the partition: ' partition_size

break

fi

if [ "$option" == "delete" ]

then
 
read -r -p 'Delete partition: Please define a name of the partition: ' delete_partition

break

fi

if [ "$option" == "new" ]

then
 
read -r -p 'Reset memory usage: Please define a name of the partition: ' reset_partition

break

fi

if [ "$option" == "quit" ]

then

break

fi

done
```

Comment: 1. learn to indent your code so that it's readable.  2. install and use `shellcheck` (or paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/) - your code will not run as is, due to multiple instances where there is a missing space after `[` and before `]`.  3. you should also double-quote your variables, including `$option`.

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you enter to the `select` prompt will be reflected in the `$REPLY` variable. Unfortunately you have to hit the "enter" key to terminate the input. So `$REPLY` will hold the "c", "d", "n", or "q" character, whenever either was entered, and you can run a `case` statement on it:

```
PS3="enter create, delete, new, quit, and hit <Return> "
select OP in create delete new quit
  do echo ">$OP<, >$REPLY<"
  done
1) create
2) delete
3) new
4) quit
enter create, delete, new, quit, and hit <Return> c
><, >c<
enter create, delete, new, quit, and hit <Return> d
><, >d<
enter create, delete, new, quit, and hit <Return> 1
>create<, >1<
enter create, delete, new, quit, and hit <Return>
```

Comment: My idea was if you enter a character "c" then the program jumps to "create" and so on.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid, you can't use `select`. Try `read -n1` instead.

Comment: maybe use [iselect](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/tool/iselect/) instead.  it's not a built-in like `select` is, but it is "ncurses-enhanced" and  does have some extra features that select doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Read input and then case switch:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo select... c: create, d: delete, x:xxx...

read OPT

case $OPT in
c*)
echo c
;;

d*)
echo d
;;

*)
echo “User Selected Choice not present”
exit 1

esac
```